# Segmentation fault when parsing text file with using strtok_r()

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

I have text file with multiple lines. Like:

```
11111111
22222222
33333333
44444444
55555555
...
```

I wrote a c code to retrieve each line. My code parsed all lines and wrote them to output console succesfully. But after the last line app crashed. It returns

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

Why is that?

My C Code:

```
FILE *fPtr;
char file[]="/root/dd";

char *rest;
char *token;
char *buffer;

unsigned long size;

fPtr = fopen(file,"r"); 

fseek(fPtr, 0, SEEK_END);
size=(unsigned long)ftell(fPtr);
fseek(fPtr, 0, SEEK_SET);

buffer=(char *)malloc(size);    

if(fPtr)
{   
    while(fgets(buffer, size, fPtr))    
    {
        while(token = strtok_r(buffer, "\n", &rest))
        {
            printf("token: %s\n", token);
            buffer = rest;
        }
    }
    fclose(fPtr);
}
else
{
     printf("file not open \n");
}
```

**UPDATE**

I thins problem is not related with strtok_r(). Because I changed my code:

```
FILE *fPtr;
char file[]="/root/dd";

char *rest;
char *token;
char *buffer;

unsigned long size;

fPtr = fopen(file,"r");

if(fPtr==NULL)
{
     printf("null pointer\n");
}

fseek(fPtr, 0, SEEK_END);
size=(unsigned long)ftell(fPtr);
fseek(fPtr, 0, SEEK_SET);

buffer=(char *)malloc(size);    

if(fPtr)
{   
    while(fgets(buffer, size, fPtr))    
    {
         printf("buffer: %s\n", buffer);
    }
    fclose(fPtr);
}
else
{
     printf("file not open \n");
}
```

And still same thing happens.

Comment: You should check `fPtr` for null *before* you try to use it, instead of after the fseeking.

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). Also, you allocate room for the entire file, then still use `fgets()` to read it line by line. That's two halves of two *different* solutions to the problem of loading a file ...

Comment: Is `size` the value you expect?  You should also check `buffer` for null before you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is definition of `char c[]="...";`

it should be `char c[20]="...";`

Answer (score 2):

I think you call to `strtok_r` is wrong, quote from the manual

> #include
>
> char *strtok_r(char *s1, const char *s2, char **s3);
>
> To get the first token from s1, strtok_r() is called with s1 as its
>   first parameter. Remaining tokens from s1 are obtained by calling
>   strtok_r() with a null pointer for the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The second and subsequent calls to `strtok_r` should have the first parameter as `NULL`.  However, I'm not sure this is why you have the segfault.

You are also changing where `buffer` points to in the line

```
buffer = rest;
```

when you have read the whole file and exit the `fgets` line runs again, `buffer` no longer points to a block of memory of size `size`.  I suspect this is causing your segfault.

Also, by modifying `buffer` you have no way of `free`ing the memory that was `malloc`